# Mocked service not called

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, junit4

I have the following code.

```
SingleLoanDTO singleLoanDto;

@Mock
private SingleLoanService singleLoanService;

@Autowired
@InjectMocks
private LoanFacadeImpl loanFacadeImpl;

@Autowired
private MappingService mappingService;

setSingleLoanDto();
final long fake_id = 43252343;
```

Then I do some mock.

```
Mockito.when(
    singleLoanService.createSingleLoan(
        mappingService.mapTo(singleLoanDto, SingleLoan.class)
    )
).thenReturn(fake_id);
```

And assert, that it works.

```
Assert.assertEquals(fake_id,
    singleLoanService.createSingleLoan(
        mappingService.mapTo(singleLoanDto, SingleLoan.class)
));
```

However, instead of calling the mocked version, the code seems to call the real one.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :43252343
Actual   :0
```

The mapping by `mappingService` works. Why is the mocked version not called?

Comment: either use `@InjectMocks` **or** `@Autowired` but not both

Comment: @Lino Sorry, the `loanFacadeImpl` is not related to the question. I do not execute it in the problem above. Nevertheless, I noticed our teacher uses them at the same time. I guessed it would use dependency injection to insert the mocked `SingleLoanService` into the working `LoanFacadeImpl` implementation. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: You either mock the dependencies yourselves and inject them via `@InjectMocks` or you use spring to create the dependencies and let it inject them. To use them together you'd have to do a bit more than what you've shown. (It's definetely possible, but requires a custom `@Configuration`, where you provide the mocks...)

Comment: If you want to use mockito in a spring-test you need ```@MockBean``` instead of ```@Mock```. As other users said, remove the ```@InjectMocks```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the object that `createSingleLoan` takes is different when you set when and assert

```
when(singleLoanService.createSingleLoan(any())).thenReturn(fake_id);
```

Comment: But `mapTo` is not mocked, it is a real Dozer 6.5.0 mapTo implementation from com.github.dozermapper. I have checked the mapping and it is correct. I might check again, though. It should work without mocking mapTo, right?

Comment: @Slazer any luck!

Comment: Yes, it works with `any()`! Why are the objects not equal, though? I implemented `SingleLoan.equal()`. Do you think it is implemented incorrectly? (nice pun by the way :) )

Comment: yes I guess because if it the same object then assert should pass

Comment: @Slazer Could you approve the answer :)